# Glide for album art fails with JNI errors

Tags: java, android, xml, android-glide, albumart

I am using glide library for displaying album art in my music player app. But I don't know why it isn't not working .

Here is the java file :   **PlayListActivity.java**

```
package com.example.dell_1.myapp3;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

public class PlayListActivity extends Activity {

    private String[] mAudioPath;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private String[] mMusicList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_list);

        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        mMusicList = getAudioList();

        ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mMusicList);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                                    long arg3) {

                try {
                    playSong(mAudioPath[arg2]);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private String[] getAudioList() {
        final Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA}, null, null,
                "LOWER(" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + ") ASC");

        int count = mCursor.getCount();

        String[] songs = new String[count];
        mAudioPath = new String[count];
        int i = 0;
        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                songs[i] = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                mAudioPath[i] = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                i++;
            } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
        }

        mCursor.close();

        return songs;
    }

    private void playSong(String path) throws IllegalArgumentException,
            IllegalStateException, IOException {

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_building_music_player);
        Log.d("ringtone", "playSong :: " + path);

        mMediaPlayer.reset();
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
//mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer.start();

        asd();

    }

    public void asd() {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.coverart);


        File music = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
        // Tested with music from Windows 7's c:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music
        String filePath = new File(music, "I love you.mp3").getAbsolutePath();
        Glide
                .with(this)
                .load(new AudioCover(filePath))
                .placeholder(R.drawable.adele1)
                .error(R.drawable.adele1)
                .into(imageView)
        ;

    }
}
```

Here is the xml file : activity_play_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:divider="#242424"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_android_building_music_player.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/player_header_bg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@layout/bg_player_header"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/songTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:text="The Good, The Bad And The Ugly"
            android:textColor="#04b3d2"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPlaylist"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_playlist" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/songThumbnail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/player_header_bg"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/coverart"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/player_footer_bg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@layout/bg_player_footer"
        android:gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:weightSum="1">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnPrevious"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2.40"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/btn_previous" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnPlay1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/btn_play"
                    android:onClick="buttonAction1"/>


                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnNext"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="250dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/btn_next" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/songProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/player_footer_bg"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/timerDisplay"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/timerDisplay"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"
        android:thumb="@drawable/download8" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/timerDisplay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/songProgressBar"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/songCurrentDurationLabel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#eeeeee"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/songTotalDurationLabel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#04cbde"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/timerDisplay"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnRepeat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_repeat" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnShuffle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_shuffle" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**AudioCover.java**

```
package com.example.dell_1.myapp3;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever;

import com.bumptech.glide.*;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.data.DataFetcher;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.model.GenericLoaderFactory;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.model.ModelLoader;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.model.ModelLoaderFactory;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.model.stream.StreamModelLoader;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class AudioCover {
    final String path;
    public AudioCover(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }
}

class AudioCoverLoader implements StreamModelLoader<AudioCover> {
    @Override public DataFetcher<InputStream> getResourceFetcher(AudioCover model, int width, int height) {
        return new AudioCoverFetcher(model);
    }

    static class Factory implements ModelLoaderFactory<AudioCover, InputStream> {
        @Override public ModelLoader<AudioCover, InputStream> build(Context context, GenericLoaderFactory factories) {
            return new AudioCoverLoader();
        }
        @Override public void teardown() {
        }
    }
}
class AudioCoverFetcher implements DataFetcher<InputStream> {
    private final AudioCover model;
    private FileInputStream stream;

    public AudioCoverFetcher(AudioCover model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    @Override public String getId() {
        return model.path;
    }

    @Override public InputStream loadData(Priority priority) throws Exception {
        MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        try {
            retriever.setDataSource(model.path);
            byte[] picture = retriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
            if (picture != null) {
                return new ByteArrayInputStream(picture);
            } else {
                return fallback(model.path);
            }
        } finally {
            retriever.release();
        }
    }

    private static final String[] FALLBACKS = {"cover.jpg", "album.jpg", "folder.jpg"};
    private InputStream fallback(String path) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File parent = new File(path).getParentFile();
        for (String fallback : FALLBACKS) {
            // TODO make it smarter by enumerating folder contents and filtering for files
            // example algorithm for that: http://askubuntu.com/questions/123612/how-do-i-set-album-artwork
            File cover = new File(parent, fallback);
            if (cover.exists()) {
                return stream = new FileInputStream(cover);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override public void cleanup() {
        // already cleaned up in loadData and ByteArrayInputStream will be GC'd
        if (stream != null) {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException ignore) {
                // can't do much about it
            }
        }
    }
    @Override public void cancel() {
        // cannot cancel
    }
}
```

Here is the manifest :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            package="com.example.dell_1.myapp3">

                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE" />
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
                 <uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL" />
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

                <application
                    android:allowBackup="true"
                    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:label="@string/app_name"
                    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
                    android:supportsRtl="true"
                    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
                    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
                    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE" />
                    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
                    <uses-permission 
                    android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL" />
                    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

                    <activity
                        android:name=".apples"
                        android:label="@string/app_name"
                        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
                        <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                        </intent-filter>
                    </activity>
                    <activity
                        android:name=".Bacon1"
                        android:label="@string/title_activity_bacon1" />
                    <activity
                        android:name=".SDCard"
                        android:label="@string/title_activity_sdcard" />

                    <meta-data android:name="my.app.namespace.utils.GlideConfiguration"
                        android:value="GlideModule"/>


                    <activity
                        android:name=".PlayListActivity"
                        android:label="@string/title_activity_play_list"></activity>
                </application>

            </manifest>
```

I figured out I get following error on clicking button4 :

```
07-11 17:11:04.222 13978-13978/com.example.dell_1.myapp3 E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails
07-11 17:11:04.222 13978-13978/com.example.dell_1.myapp3 E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
07-11 17:11:04.222 13978-13978/com.example.dell_1.myapp3 E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails
07-11 17:11:04.222 13978-13978/com.example.dell_1.myapp3 E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
```

Comment: you have to locate where it fails. so if it fails on the retrieving image, or on setting image, etc.

Comment: I thought logcat would help me in locating, but it shows nothing relevant in logcat too

Comment: you can use debug, breakpoints, and step-over/step-into

Comment: add .listener(...) to Glide to understand why doesn't work

Comment: Getting an error saying "Cannot resolve method 'listener(anonymous com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestListener<java.lang.String,com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.drawable.GlideDrawable>)"

Comment: I have updated logcat. does it tell anything ??

Answer (score 0):

Have you provided the necessary access to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Comment: yes I have certainly. I have included manifest file now. You can take a look .Thanks

Comment: What's your Android API?

Comment: API 14: Android 4.0 (IceCreamSandwich)

Comment: I already requested access to external storage at run time in another java file which is working fine and access to Internet is a normal permission so I dont need to request at run time I guess